# Find sum() from two different tables and join them based on a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables,

Table1:

```
ID   Amount  Date
------------------
123  500.00  02-Sep-2020
123  240.00  02-Sep-2020
124  200.50  02-Sep-2020
125  150.70  03-Sep-2020
123  480.80  03-Sep-2020
```

Table2

```
ID   Settled_Amount  Date
-------------------------------
123    150.25       02-Sep-2020
124    200.00       03-Sep-2020
125    100.40       03-Sep-2020
```

I want to sum the Amount column of table1 and sum the settled_amount column of Table2 of a particular ID group by the Date column.

So My result would be for ID=123:

```
Sum(Amount) Sum(Settled_amount) Date
------------------------------------------
740.00       150.25             02-Sep-2020
480.80                          03-Sep-2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` and `group by`.  For all `id`s:

```
select id, date, sum(amount), sum(amount_settled)
from ((select id, date, amount, null as amount_settled
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select id, date, null as amount, amount_settled
       from table2
      ) 
     ) t
group by id, date
order by date;
```

You can filter for a particular `id` using a `where` clause in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it without subseleting as Gordon does.

```
declare @table1 table  (id int, amount numeric(18,2), Dates Date)

Insert into @table1
values 
(123 ,500.00  ,'02-Sep-2020'),
(123 ,240.00  ,'02-Sep-2020'),
(124 ,200.50  ,'02-Sep-2020'),
(125 ,150.70  ,'03-Sep-2020'),
(123 ,480.80  ,'03-Sep-2020')

declare @table2 table  (id int, Settled_Amount numeric(18,2), Dates Date)
insert into @table2
values 
(123   , 150.25      ,'02-Sep-2020'),
(124   , 200.00      ,'03-Sep-2020'),
(125   , 100.40      ,'03-Sep-2020');

with Table1 as (
select sum(amount) as Amount,ID,Dates from @table1
group by ID,Dates
)
,
Table2 as (
Select sum(Settled_amount) as Settled_amount, ID,Dates from @table2
group by ID,Dates
)

select Amount,Settled_amount,a.Dates,a.ID from Table1 a left join table2 b on a.id = b.id and a.Dates = b.Dates

where a.id=123
```